# Make a percentage depending on DF

Tags: r, dataframe, percentage

I have a train set here and I need you to help me with something.

This is the df.

```
              Jobs       Agency      Location       Date RXH   HS  TMM Payed
14 Netapp Gitex F1 Events House          DWTC 2015-10-19 100  8.0  800  TRUE
5     RWC Heineken    Lightblue           EGC 2015-10-09  90  4.0  360 FALSE
45        Rugby 7s          CEO Seven Stadium 2015-12-04 100 10.0 1000 FALSE
29     Playstation    Lightblue    Mirdiff CC 2015-11-11  90  7.0  630 FALSE
24    RWC Heineken    Lightblue           EGC 2015-10-31  90  4.5  405 FALSE
33     Playstation    Lightblue    Mirdiff CC 2015-11-15  90 10.0  900 FALSE
46        Rugby 7s          CEO Seven Stadium 2015-12-05 100 10.0 1000 FALSE
44        Rugby 7s          CEO Seven Stadium 2015-12-03 100 10.0 1000 FALSE
```

I want to know **for example** that the total of rows is 10, and I worked for " CEO" agency 3 times, I want CEO Agency to have the 30% value for that month, if that makes sense?

I want to know depending on the number of observations how much in % i ve worked for them.

Thats just a Demo DF to see what im talking about.

Thanks

Comment: Simplest way would be to create a counter column full of 1's and then aggregate the counter column by agency and divide each aggregate by the total count.

Comment: Cannot tell what you what exactly, but take a look at `100*prop.table(table(df$Agency))`. If you want this done by-month then use two arguments to table rather than one. There are many worked examples in SO on creating tabular summaries. If you do find a duplicate, you should probably delete your question. If not, then you should make your example sufficiently complex to get an answer that covers the areas about which you are unable to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to summarize by Agency and by month. Here's how to do it with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
table1 %>%
mutate(Month=format(Date,"%m-%Y")) %>%
group_by(Month,Agency)%>%
summarise(Total=n())%>%
mutate(Pct=round(Total/sum(Total)*100))

Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
Groups: Month [3]

    Month       Agency Total   Pct
    (chr)        (chr) (int) (dbl)
1 10-2015 Events House     1    33
2 10-2015    Lightblue     2    67
3 11-2015    Lightblue     2   100
4 12-2015          CEO     3   100
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted. Thank you for sharing your knowledge and helping me out.

Comment: The only issue im having is when I run it in a bigger DF it only prints 10 Results and then just prints dots

.... .........

Comment: Add these two `dplyr` options at the begging of your script (after you call the package). `library(dplyr);options(dplyr.print_max = 1e9);options(dplyr.width = Inf)`

Answer (score 2):

This is just a simple approach, and I suspect you might be looking for more. However, here's some code that would give you the answer to your sample question:

```
length(df$Agency[df$Agency == "CEO"]) / length(df$Agency)
```

The first length() function calculates how many cells in df$Agency are marked "CEO," then the second one calculates the total number of cells in that column. Dividing one by the other will give you the answer.

This will get more complicated if you want to automatically do this for each of the agencies in the column, but there are the basics.